# Capistrano3 - Delete failed release on deploy:failed

Tags: capistrano

I'm using Capistrano 3. How can I delete failed releases on deploy:failed without writing my own task? The point is that failed releases stay in the releases directory and accidentally I can rollback to broken release by typing cap deploy:rollback
UPD:
For now I'm using this task but still looking for a better solution.

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Delete failed release'  
  task :rm_failed do  
    on roles(:all) do  
      execute(:rm, "-rf #{release_path}")
    end
  end

end

after 'deploy:failed', 'deploy:rm_failed'
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution. If deploy:cleanup fails, this task will be called and your release will be removed... AFTER it has been released into production by deploy:symlink:release!

Answer (score 0):

My limited experience with Capistrano indicates that there is no built-in mechanism to perform the action you want. Writing a task that is triggered using deploy:failed is the proper way to handle the situation as it can be application specific.

A better solution that addresses the potential for deploy:clean to fail after the deploy:symlink:release --

```
namespace :deploy do

    desc 'Delete failed release'
    task :rm_failed do
        on roles(:web) do
            if test "[ -d #{current_path} ]"
                current_release = capture(:readlink, current_path).to_s
                if current_release != release_path.to_s
                    execute :rm, "-rf #{release_path}"
                end
            end
        end
    end

end

after 'deploy:failed', 'deploy:rm_failed'
```

The [Capistrano page on rollbacks](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/rollbacks/) has a larger discussion on handling rollbacks and failures.